# Split NSString to array by specific word

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsstring

I need to split `NSString` to array by specific word.

I've tried to use `[componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]]`

But the split is performed by a single character, and I need a few chars.

Example:

```
NSString @"Hello great world";
```

Split key == @" great ";

result:

```
array[0] == @"Hello";
array[1] == @"world";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
NSString *str = @"Hello great world"; 
//you can use the bellow line to remove space   
//str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];       
// split key = @"great"

NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"great"];
```

Comment: unfortunately, no one is reading the question carefully, what is the requirment

Comment: but in this answer , u get the array[1] == @"   world"; not like array[1] == @"world";, how would u say this is correct man

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - Well spotted. I think that was just a simple typo, fixed it for them.

Comment: or simply you can  avoid white spaces

Comment: This is still a bit naive solution. What if the word is the last word? E.g. "That's great." The best solution would probably be using a regular expression. This will work for simple cases but won't work in general.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello great world";
NSArray *stringArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @" great "];

NSLog(@"Array 0: %@" [stringArray objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"Array 1: %@" [stringArray objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is the following:

NSString *string = @"Hello Great World";

NSArray *stringArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];

This can help you.